# SQL for total sales for each customer for each year

Tags: sql, sum, advantage-database-server

Using Advantage Database Server 11
I'm trying to find each customers total purchase from two types for comparison year by year, but I get an error:

[iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Expected 
lexical element not found: THEN

Here are the table.

```
customernr | Date_in | Status | InvType | Qty | Total
1111          9/1/2018            D         5    25.00
1111         12/1/2018   V        D         3    15.00
1111         5/12/2019            L         1     2.00
1111         7/11/2019            D         5    35.00
1112         6/21/2018            L         7    18.00
1112         9/14/2019            L         3     7.00


Select 
customernr,
SUM(CASE WHEN date_in >= '2018-01-01' and date_in <= '2018-12-31' total 
and InvType='D' ELSE 0 END) LastYD,
SUM(CASE WHEN date_in >= '2018-01-01' and date_in <= '2018-12-31' total 
and InvType='L' ELSE 0 END) LastYL,
SUM(CASE WHEN date_in >= '2019-01-01' and date_in <= '2019-12-31' total 
and InvType='D' ELSE 0 END) ThisYD,
SUM(CASE WHEN date_in >= '2019-01-01' and date_in <= '2019-12-31' total 
and InvType='L' ELSE 0 END) ThisYL

from invoice
where (Status <> 'V' or Status IS NULL)

Group by Customernr
```

Thanks for any help,

KHJ

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you'll find your SQL will be more readable if you use `BETWEEN` rather than `>=` and `<=`, as in `WHEN date_in BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'`. You might also find it easier to use `YEAR(date_in)` instead, and add that column to the GROUP BY.

Comment: Thanks, since I just need year total YEAR would be best, thanks again still learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a missing `THEN` on your `CASE` statement

```
Select 
customernr,
SUM(CASE WHEN date_in >= '2018-01-01' and date_in <= '2018-12-31' 
and InvType='D' THEN total ELSE 0 END) LastYD,
SUM(CASE WHEN date_in >= '2018-01-01' and date_in <= '2018-12-31' 
and InvType='L' THEN total ELSE 0 END) LastYL,
SUM(CASE WHEN date_in >= '2019-01-01' and date_in <= '2019-12-31' 
and InvType='D' THEN total ELSE 0 END) ThisYD,
SUM(CASE WHEN date_in >= '2019-01-01' and date_in <= '2019-12-31' 
and InvType='L' THEN total ELSE 0 END) ThisYL

from invoice
where (Status <> 'V' or Status IS NULL)

Group by Customernr
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what happens when you make a mistake in the first line and copy and paste the whole way down.